# Find if a class derives from another class which is generic in .NET?

Tags: .net, generics, inheritance, types

I have a class like:

```
class A<T>
{

}
```

I have another class that derives from above class like:

```
class B : A<X>
{

}
```

Above X is another class.

Now I can have many classes like B, and in those classes the generic parameter could be some other class.

How do I figure out if any instance of class like B is deriving from class A ?

I tried:

```
if objB.GetType() is typeof(A<object>) //didn't work, gave false

if objB.GetType() == typeof(A<object>) //didn't work, gave false

if typeof(A<object>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) //didn't work, gave false
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is problematic; no `IsAssignableFrom` test will work there unless you already know `X`. You would have to do something like:

```
static bool IsA(Type type) {
    do {
        type = type.BaseType;
        if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(A<>))
           return true;
    } while(type != null && type != typeof(object));
    return false;
}
```

or to also get the `T`:

```
static bool IsA(Type type, out Type t)
{
    do
    {
        type = type.BaseType;
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(A<>))
        {
            t = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            return true;
        }
    } while (type != null && type != typeof(object));
    t = null;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstood the question a bit... here's what I would do in that situation - but note that the sample below will only work 1 level deep.  If you think or know other objects would derive from B, then loop until BaseType is object and use the current type name. OR, you can seal B so that it cannot be derived from.

```
    public class A<T>
    {

    }

    public class X
    {

    }

    public class B : A<X>
    {


    }


    void Test()
    {
        B obj = new B();

        if(b.GetType().BaseType.Name == "A`1")
        {
            Consosle.WriteLine(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Warning 1 The given expression is never of the provided ('A<object>') type` - even the compiler knows that this is never true

Comment: no, it is because `A<X>` is not an `A<object>`. Your approach only works if you know the `X` in advance. See "Now I can have many classes like B, and in those classes the generic parameter could be some other class. How do I figure out if any instance of class like B is deriving from class A ?"

Comment: @MarcGravell - thanks for pointing out the obvious :)  I misunderstood what the OP wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, here's some pure evil for you... exploit `dynamic` to hijack the reflection; the key point here being that `dynamic` has some type-based caching built in, so it won't do the heavy lifting each time (only once per type):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsA("abc"));   // False
    Console.WriteLine(IsA(new B())); // True
    Console.WriteLine(IsA(123));     // False
    Console.WriteLine(IsA(new D())); // True - where D : B
}
public static bool IsA(object o)
{
    return (bool)EvilOnlyUseDynamicToCallThis((dynamic)o);
}

private static bool EvilOnlyUseDynamicToCallThis(object o)
{
    return false;
}
private static bool EvilOnlyUseDynamicToCallThis<T>(A<T> a)
{
    return true;
}
```